# Comparing 2 strings fails in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am seeing a strange issue. I am trying to compare 2 strings in Swift. One string is from the response I got from server. In the below code, it is printing as "Error" in outputString NSLog properly. But, when I do sting comparison in the next below line, it fails, it doesn't throw the error alert there. I don't know what i'm doing wrong here.

```
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
    var outputString:NSString = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    NSLog("outputString: %@", outputString)
    if (outputString=="Error") {
      NSLog("Error")
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a trailing space or carriage return on `outputString`? try `var newString = outputString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())` and `if (newString == "Error")...`

Comment: it says NSCharacterSet doesn't have whitespaceCharacterS‌​et

Comment: Tried but not solved,    let outputString = responseString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())

Comment: The docs have it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/whitespaceCharacterSet did you see that special character in your comments (and mine too ;)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `NSString` Class Reference : http://goo.gl/rPwMUx
>
> Swift Library Reference - `String` : http://goo.gl/591Ebo

The two are different. So you won't be able to apply certain operation on one or the other.

In order to compare two `String` you can do `outputString == "Error"` because the comparison operators exists.

However, in order to compare two `NSString` you need to use the `isEqualToString:` method. In your case, it should work like so : `outputString.isEqualToString("Error")`.

**Edit 1 :**

Code examples here : http://swiftstub.com/445434073/

**Edit 2 :**

You can also compare `String` with a `NSString` with the `==` operator.

Comment: Tried, outputString.isEqualToString("Error") but still condition is failing.

Comment: Can you show us (screenshot ?) what is the `outputString` exact value ?

Comment: Code tried now is, var responseString:NSString = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!    if (responseString.isEqualToString("Error")) { }

Comment: NSLog("responseString: %@", responseString) - This prints-> 2015-03-17 17:35:46.340 DocuScan[21654:924739] responseString: Error

Comment: Even with the string being trimmed, as mentioned by @pherris ?
 `var trimmedResponseString = responseString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())` followed by `if (trimmedResponseString.isEqualToString("Error")) { }`

Comment: I get this error->NSCharacterSet doesn't have whitespaceCharacterS‌​et

Comment: There was a weird character in the `whitespaceAndNewli‌​neCharacterSet()`. I re-write it manually and it worked (no more the NSCharacterSet error). Glad it work for you too :)

Comment: I've added edited the answer as well to include few code examples.

Comment: The comment *in order to compare two NSString you need to use the isEqualToString: method* is false, you can compare an NSString with a Swift string literal using `==`.  Just tried it in a test case and it passed.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue and the reason was a wrong encoding.
I used UTF8 encoding, but the string I was comparing to was encoded with UTF16

```
String(data: model, encoding: .utf16) == String(data: data, encoding: .utf18)
```

is false

Comment: Wow, I found my own post while searching for this issue again. Thanks to myself. :D