# UIDevice Name unexplainably won't compare

Tags: swift, uidevice

This app runs on two phones (Master/Slave). I was distinguishing the phones by screen size but we had to replace one (same size).

So I decide to make the distinction using `UIDevice.current.name` instead. This is in ViewDidLoad

```
print(UIDevice.current.name)

if UIDevice.current.name == "Slave" {isSlavePhone = true;print("SLAVE PHONE")}

else if UIDevice.current.name == "Master" {print("MASTER PHONE")}

else {print("error")}
```

which gives this output

> Slave
>
> error

So it `gets` `UIDevice.current.name` showing as "Slave". I verified there's no space at end with `.count`. But when the If/Else runs it doesn't match.

I'm confused and would like to know why. Also curious any other ways to distinguish devices that might work for now.

Comment: Could this strangely be because of encoding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42126323/1801544 ?

Comment: @Larme not sure, if I set `let device = UIDevice.current.name`, device is a String not NSString. Also oddly, `if device.contains("Slave")` does fire.